# OSError: [Errno 1] EPERM connecting to WLAN on Raspberry Pi Pico W

Tags: wifi, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, thonny

OSError: [Errno 1] EPERM how to solve this error whenever i try to connect wifi this error arrives

i need to solve this error and connect my pico w to wifi. when ever i upload the code using thonny and selected micropython pico and run the code but it showing in the wlan connect line.
my code:

```
import network
import time
ssid = 'xxxxxx'
password = 'xxxxxx'
import urequests
def connect_Wifi(s,b):
    #Connect to WLAN
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)
    wlan.connect(s,b)
    wait = 10
    while wait>0:
        if wlan.status()<0 or wlan.status() >= 3:
            break
        wait -=1
        print('Waiting for connection...')
        time.sleep(1)
    if wlan.status()!=3:
        raise RuntimeError('Wifi connection failed')
    else:
        ip = wlan.ifconfig()[0]
        print(f'Connected on {ip}',ip)
        return ip
connect_Wifi(ssid,password)
```

Comment: So the OSError is raised by the line `wlan.connect(s,b)` ?

Comment: Yes i can't able to rectify it, other coding or running in the Pico w except this wifi connection

Comment: Are you sure your Pico can see your network and you have specified the SSID and password correctly? After creating a `WLAN` object and making it active, what do you get from [`wlan.scan()`](https://docs.micropython.org/en/v1.22.0/library/network.WLAN.html#network.WLAN.scan) ?

Comment: Yes whenever i try to connect the wifi by running the code . exactly this line  "wlan.connect(s,b)" and  this error OSError: [Errno 1] EPERM will popuping